# How can I programmatically read the file signcode signing time?

Tags: delphi, winapi, signtool

How to get a digital signcode signing time from an exe file in Delphi / winapi code?

[image]

Comment: Are you talking how to get this time from within Delphi code? Or how to find it for a file compiled in Delphi?

Comment: @JerryDodge how to get this time from generic *.exe file with Delphi code

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Microsoft explains this here: http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323809

I've found this page in Russian with alot of informations that looks hansom : http://www.sql.ru/forum/745519/dobavlenie-atributa-daty-v-ecp

I haven't testet it but, I think with theese two links you have enough to get on.

Comment: There is also an other SO question about the same with som answers written in c++ : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024583/how-to-retrieve-files-digital-signature-information